# How to make a bat file open itself a certain number of times

Tags: batch-file

I have a bat file that I have to rapid fire click to make it open a lot but I want to make it so I just click it once and it opens like 50 times.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would simply call the script inside of a `for /L` loop via the command line.

```
for /L %A in (1,1,50) do start "" cmd /c script.bat
```

You could also write a wrapper script with the same code (although change `%A` to `%%A`).

If that's not acceptable for some reason, you can also keep track of how many times the script is open with a temporary file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set SCRIPT_INSTANCES=50

:: Create a temporary file if one doesn't already exist
if not exist script_count.txt >script_count.txt echo(%SCRIPT_INSTANCES%

:: Read in the value of the config file
set /p script_counter=<script_count.txt

:: If the value of script_counter is greater than 1, decrement it and start again
if %script_counter% gtr 1 (
    set /a script_counter-=1
    >script_count.txt echo(!script_counter!

    start "" cmd /c "%~0"
) else (
    del script_count.txt
)

:: THE REST OF YOUR CODE GOES UNDER THIS LINE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set /a "times=%~1 -1"
if %times% gtr 0 for /L %%a in (1,1,%times%) do start "" cmd /c "%~0"
pause
```

Expected syntax to run:

> *thisbatchname* instancesrequired

If you start the batch with an argument of 3 for instance, `times` becomes 2 and 2 extra instances are created by the `for/L`

Since the extra instances have no parameter, then `times` will be set to `-1` hence no extra instances will be created.

Naturally, replace the `pause` with the required series of batch commands.